# Store and retrieve an array value using angular-local-storage in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-local-storage

Okay so I have a controller `SettingsCtrl` in my code given as :

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl' , function($scope, localStorageService) {
    $scope.verseOptions = [5 , 10, 15, 20];
    $scope.verses = JSON.stringify($scope.verseOptions);
    console.log($scope.verses);
    console.log($scope.verses[3]);
    $scope.dd = JSON.parse($scope.verses);
    console.log($scope.dd);
    var d = $scope.dd[1];
    console.log(d);

    $scope.config = {
        numVerses: localStorage.getItem('numVerses' , 23),
        selectedVerse : localStorage.setItem('verseOption' , d) || $scope.verseOptions[1]
    };

    $scope.save = function() {
     console.log($scope.config.numVerses);
     localStorage.setItem('numVerses', $scope.config.numVerses);
     localStorage.setItem('verseOption' , $scope.config.selectedVerse);
     console.log($scope.config.selectedVerse);
   };
})
```

Given the array verseOptions and config.selectedVerse .

In my ion-view, I load the `config.numVerses` value inside an input box and `config.verses` inside a drop down list as :

```
<label class="item item-input item-label">
        <span class="input-label">Number Of Verses</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="config.numVerses">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
                Verses
            </div>
            <select ng-model='config.selectedVerse'>
                <option ng-repeat='verse in dd'>
                    {{verse}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </label>
```

When a save button inside the view is clicked, it invokes the `save()` of the controller. With the save() function I want to save the array element inside the localStorage. For example, if I select 5 from the drop down, **it should save the array index having value 5 in such a way that it can be reloaded upon next start**.

For me, saving and loading numVerses value works, but the selectedVerse value (from the drop down doesnt work). When I try to reload the values on next start, numVerses shows as is, but the drop down shows as blank option selected

PS. I am using the [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just tell me what you want to do?

Comment: @CharanCherry , I have a drop down list that loads value from the verseOptions array. If I select an option, the save() should save that value and should be able to load that value on next start of the app..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ng-repeat to cycle through your list of verses try using Angulars [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

This allows you to automatically bind an array or json object to a select-option and track different aspects of those data structures to the options value field.

So you could track by array index like so:

```
<select ng-model='config.selectedVerse' 
        ng-options='verse for (idx, verse) in dd track by idx'>
</select>
```

Yielding the following html:

```
<select ng-model="config.selectedVerse" ng-options="verse for (idx, verse) in dd track by idx" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
    <option label="5" value="0">5</option>
    <option label="10" value="1">10</option>
    <option label="15" value="2">15</option>
    <option label="20" value="3">20</option>
</select>
```

Upon hitting save your ng-model (config.selectedVerse) should take on the value field from the selected option.

As for saving to local storage I'm not to familiar with the syntax of that plugin but you should be able to get and set data using the window.localStorage syntax (ensuring to stringify and parse data as its being get and set) to save it.

```
window.localStorage['myData'] = JSON.stringify(config);
$scope.myData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage[request];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want store `numVerses` array and `selectedVerse` in local storage, just do this on save(). To push an array into local storage, you must stringify it before pushing and parse after retrieving.

`$scope.config = {`

```
numVerse:localStorage.getItem('numVerses')?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('numVerses')):[],

 selectedVerse:localStorage.getItem('selectedVerse')?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedVerse')):null
```

`};`

`$scope.save = function (){`

```
$scope.config.numVerses.push($scope.selectedVerse)
```

`localStorage.setItem('numVerses', JSON.stringify($scope.config.numVerses))`

`localStorage.setItem('selectedVerse', $scope.selected verse)`
`}`